# Enable a specific row in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for a way to enable a specific row within a grid view whilst disabling the others

My grid view is called **gv_Quals**

I know how to disable the entire grid view and I have already attempted to do it myself.  Here is my attempt that does not work of course

```
gv_Quals.Rows[count - 1].Enabled = true;
```

is it possible to do this or am I doing it completely wrong?  Thanks in advance and sorry if I seem vague!

Comment: Ive edited it, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable the whole datagrid and enable 1 row.

What you have to do is disable all rows and enable the one you want

So like this:

```
//disable all rows (not the grid)
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_Quals.Rows)
    row.Enabled = false;

//enable the rows you like
gv_Quals.Rows[count - 1].Enabled = true;
```

Have a look at the following MSDN Documentation about the Enabled Property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx

There you will find the following quote:

> This property propagates down the control hierarchy. If you disable a container control, the child controls within that container are also disabled.

Comment: not working (row.Enabled) it says that the object does not contain a definition for 'Enabled'. Is there another way to disable the rows in the foreach statement?  I think I understand where you are coming from

Comment: According to docs it does have Enabled - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx try to change `var` to specific `GridViewRow` - updated my answer with that change